Why is django debug toolbar causing a 'ValueError at ... Another profiling tool is already active' error when Htmx ajax fires?
I had django-debug-toolbar working fine in my application until I added htmx. Now I'm getting Another profiling tool is already active error.

The page loads then htmx fires on load to add more content. Below is the offending line
<div id="group-list" hx-get="{% url "my-rental-property-groups" rental_property.id %}" hx-trigger="load"></div>

If I change the change the hx-trigger attribute to hx-trigger="load delay:5s" to add a delay of 5 seconds, then the error goes away but that's not a solution. A smaller delay still throws the same error.
If I add "SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK": lambda request: False, to DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG section below, the page renders fine but the Debug Toolbar is disabled
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    "SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK": lambda request: False, #THIS LINE DISABLES DEBUG TOOLBAR WIHOUT SETTING DEBUG TO FALSE    
    "SHOW_TEMPLATE_CONTEXT": True,
    "ROOT_TAG_EXTRA_ATTRS": "hx-preserve", # https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips.html#working-with-htmx-and-turbo
}

I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to keep Htmx and Django Debug Toolbar working together.

TL;DR Uncheck the Profiling checkbox in Django Debug Toolbar panel
AARGH!!! It turned out to be something stupid. I had accidentally clicked the Profiling checkbox at the bottom of the Django Debug Toolbar panel (See screenshot below). I unchecked this and everything is working fine. Obviously you have to navigate to a page that's not throwing the error to access this setting. With profiling unchecked, now I don't need the SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK setting in the config

